# Get the Event ID in the event created in the Google Calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm implementing calendar application in java using google calendar api.
I have inserted an event to the calendar with the name "Test Entry" which repeats for several weeks.
I found the calendar id in the settings of the particular. But couldn't find the event id of the Event i created.

I need the event id for the following java statement

```
Event event = service.events().get('calendarId', "eventId").execute();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use Event's [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method, which will return a list of [event resources](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) in the *items* property of the response. `Items[].id` will contain the `eventID` which would pass into your *get* method. In order to search for specific events, you can search through the items for matching properties, such as the *summary* property, which would be the title of the event.